# Error On Unity Build iOS awake Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/AppleCoreNative.framework/AppleCoreNative' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, build, gamekit

When I start on iOS my app made with unity there is a crash, and the following errors appears on the Xcode logcat:

Error loading /var/containers/Bundle/Application/41415080-22B8-4564-B5B2-CF797C0D90D0/AbstractTrivial.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework (142):  dlopen(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/41415080-22B8-4564-B5B2-CF797C0D90D0/AbstractTrivial.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework, 0x0109): Library not loaded: @rpath/AppleCoreNative.framework/AppleCoreNative
Referenced from: <1F62AA76-AD50-3298-AD4B-D025F40574D3> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/41415080-22B8-4564-B5B2-CF797C0D90D0/AbstractTrivial.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework
Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/AppleCoreNative.framework/AppleCoreNative' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/AppleCoreNative.framework/AppleCoreNative' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/41415080-22B8-4564-B5B2-CF797C0D90D0/AbstractTrivial.app/Frameworks/AppleCoreNative.framework/AppleCoreNative' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/<…>

I state that:
I have installed the Apple Gamekit and GameCore in the project, and also Admob and firebase analytics.
On Monobehaviour Start() methot I make the call GKLocalPlayer.Authenticate().

Any ideas on how to fix it, or about what is the cause the errors?